# Как сделать UIButton-ссылку (например на YouTube)?

Tags: swift, xcode

Основной части нет, просто отдельный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Предполагается, что к этому коду прилагается вьюха с кнопкой. ViewController привязан к этому классу, а @IBAction привязан к кнопке (извините, что пишу это, так как не знаю вашего уровня).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9YxpwWNK9k")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
  }
  
}
```